# Exception when updating config map using kubernates client

Tags: kubernetes, okhttp, configmap, fabric8, fabric8-kubernetes-client

UseCase : When updating configmap with new entries along with existing entries.

Issue : We are seeing below exception and I am not able to reproduce below issue frequently.

I went through decompiled version but couldn't find cause of this issue . Could some one help on when this issue can happen. How can we resolve this ?

**Code used to update ConfigMap :**

> KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient(new
> ConfigBuilder().build()); final ConfigMapBuilder configMapBuilder =
> new ConfigMapBuilder().withNewMetadata()
> .withName(deploy_config).endMetadata(); configMapBuilder.addToData(status, status.name());
> client.configMaps().withName(deploy_config).createOrReplace(configMapBuilder.build());

**Exception:**

```
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: An error has occurred.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:103) ~[kubernetes-client-5.12.2.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:97) ~[kubernetes-client-5.12.2.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.CreateOnlyResourceOperation.create(CreateOnlyResourceOperation.java:63) ~[kubernetes-client-5.12.2.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.CreateOrReplaceHelper.createOrReplace(CreateOrReplaceHelper.java:48) ~[kubernetes-client-5.12.2.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.createOrReplace(BaseOperation.java:318) ~[kubernetes-client-5.12.2.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.createOrReplace(BaseOperation.java:83) ~[kubernetes-client-5.12.2.jar:?]

Caused by: java.io.IOException: closed
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Writer.data(Http2Writer.kt:150) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection.writeData(Http2Connection.kt:332) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$FramingSink.emitFrame(Http2Stream.kt:565) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$FramingSink.close(Http2Stream.kt:612) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at okio.ForwardingSink.close(ForwardingSink.kt:37) ~[okio-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange$RequestBodySink.close(Exchange.kt:242) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at okio.RealBufferedSink.close(RealBufferedSink.kt:286) ~[okio-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:60) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:62) ~[kubernetes-client-5.12.2.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:62) ~[kubernetes-client-5.12.2.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:62) ~[kubernetes-client-5.12.2.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:62) ~[kubernetes-client-5.12.2.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientImpl.send(OkHttpClientImpl.java:138) ~[kubernetes-client-5.12.2.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.retryWithExponentialBackoff(OperationSupport.java:574) ~[kubernetes-client-5.12.2.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:553) ~[kubernetes-client-5.12.2.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:518) ~[kubernetes-client-5.12.2.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleCreate(OperationSupport.java:305) ~[kubernetes-client-5.12.2.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleCreate(BaseOperation.java:644) ~[kubernetes-client-5.12.2.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleCreate(BaseOperation.java:83) ~[kubernetes-client-5.12.2.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.CreateOnlyResourceOperation.create(CreateOnlyResourceOperation.java:61) ~[kubernetes-client-5.12.2.jar:?]
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Just the exception isn't really enough to tell what's going on.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error. I exactly use code in section "Code used to update ConfigMap" . wanted to understand what could be senerios this error would be thrown.

Comment: Which version of Fabric8 Kubernetes Client are you using?

Comment: im using 5.12.2 version